# Loading image from a URL fails on Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin

I have configured my android application to download images into an image view using Coil. This works fine on every Android version except for 10. I attempted to use Glide instead, and got the same results.

When I did used glide, I received an unknown host exception only in Android 10.

I have the following setup:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and

```kotlin
profile_image_view.load("https://via.placeholder.com/150"){
    crossfade(true)
    placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
    transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
}
```

The dependency is as follows:

```
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil:0.11.0'
```

I researched this quite heavily and received many suggestions, most of which were manifest changes. I made these, and they resulted in the following in my AndroidManifest.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

These did not make a difference.

I wanted to ask if there's something that I've missed here, or some special situation with android 10 that I don't know about?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you literally failing on `https://via.placeholder.com/150`, or is that itself a placeholder for the real URL (that you are redacting in the question)? And, can you edit your question and provide the full stack trace?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have redacted the url, yeah!
There's no stacktrace with coil. It literally just fails to load.

Comment: I have not used Coil yet. It looks like you can set up a `listener` on which you can have an `onError()` function. You might try adding one of those and see if it gets called, in which case the supplied `Throwable` may give you some clues. The other callback functions (e.g., `onCancel()`) might also give you some more ideas of how far Coil is getting. "There's no stacktrace with coil. It literally just fails to load" -- do you have the stack trace from Glide? There is a decent chance it is the same problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare I noted that in the question as I had that error when attempting to use a different library - I have not seen that using Coil. I added a listener as you suggested and I do get an "UnkownHostException". This makes little sense as I can request the URL in chrome, and also in android pre 10.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I corrected the comment, but too late, apparently. Is there anything unusual about the domain name of the real URL? Also, are you using this server in your app for anything other than these images, and if so, is it working for those use cases?

Comment: @CommonsWare

Nothing unusual at al about this URL, and yeah I've used this alongside a bunch of others in the app just fine. Its specifically an issue when I try to load images from it on android 10, is there something I should be looking for here? The domain is fine as I can see from using android 9 and below.

Btw - Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not much changed in Android 10 from a network security standpoint AFAIK. You can see some items [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all?hl=en#security) and see if any of them might match your situation.

Comment: Also, are you testing on a device or the emulator? If it's a device, try another Android 10 device (if you have another) or the emulator (if your app can run there). It's possible your problem is not tied to Android 10 so much as it is tied to the test device.

Comment: I've tested on both and unfortunately see the same issue on simulator and device :(

Comment: I have fixed this by disabling firebase performance plugin (may be i hasn't configured successfully.) It was throwing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/perf/network/FirebasePerfUrlConnection` this error but **coil** is not showing this anywhere. That was really irritating.